# Differences between "Alfresco Team" "Alfresco Share"

Tags: alfresco

Judging from the described features, the [Alfresco Team](http://team.alfresco.com) and [Alfresco Share](http://www.alfresco.com/products/collaboration/) products look very similar.

What are the technical differences?

Here are a few differences I have heard about, but a better list would be welcome:

- Video preview
- Preview for more Adobe products (Illustrator etc?)
- Some kind of link with Google Apps maybe?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's obsolete.  The question asked is no longer valid as time has moved on and the product has changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is need for clarification to @Heiko Robert. His answer is not valid anymore. Team has been discontinued, and it didn't replace Alfresco Enterprise.

Team was not the latest Enterprise Edition, but a cheaper license with the restrictions that @Heiko has mentioned (and some more. For example, the number of users is also limited).

Team is being replaced by the Alfresco Cloud, as you can see if you click on the "[Team Customizations](http://team.alfresco.com/support/customizations)" link posted by @Tahir Malik.

Alfresco Enterprise is well and very alive, and a new version 4 is available.

Regarding **Share**: Alfresco has two web user interfaces: one is the original, known as Alfresco Explorer, and the newest one is Alfresco Share. Alfresco Explorer is a faster UI, based on JSF, but it is more difficult to customize, and it is not being developed anymore. On the other hand, **Share** is the "second generation" UI, which is based on Surf, which is much easier to customize. At this point, Share is actively being developed, but, as far as I know, it is close to provide 100% of the functionality provided by Alfresco Explorer.

Alfresco Explorer will probably be around for several years to come, because a lot of people already developed applications on it, so that should give them time to migrate to share.

Comment: Alfresco Share has been deprecated and is being removed from future versions of Alfresco (starting with 5.0 it appears).  Share is all that's left now.

Comment: I guess that you meant to say that Alfresco Explorer has been deprecated.

Comment: Yep, sorry about that.  Yes, Explorer is gone, Share is in, and migration to Aikau is underway.  Big changes!

Answer (score 2):

It's more or less a question of licensing. Team seems to be the latest Enterprise Edition but with major limitations in

- Number of Documents
- Customization: No Customizations in any way (no custom doc models, workflows, automation, actions)
- Usage: restricted to the Share-Interface only (no Explorer, no webscripts, not integration with other systems)

I found this Blog helpful: [Alfresco Team: First Thoughts and Limitations to Consider](http://blogs.ecmconcepts.com/2011/06/alfresco-team-first-thoughts-and-limitations-to-consider/)

Anyway - if you're looking for a out of the box tool to share documents in workgroups/teams this may the tool you should look into.

Comment: there is need for clarification. Team is not the latest Enterprise Edition, but a cheaper license with the restrictions that you have mentioned (and some more. For example, the number of users is also limited). I don't think that it is being developed anymore, but and in the future it might be replaced by Alfresco Cloud.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are much technical differences, because both are build on the Surf Platform and are quite equal in functionality.

I think you should see this page of the Team Site: [Team Customizations](http://team.alfresco.com/support/customizations)

The main difference is that you can't do whatever you like with Team and you can with Share (Enterprise/Community).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few features in Alfresco Team that are new, and which aren't in Alfresco 3.4 (Enterprise or Community). Video Preview and a few more transformers are in that list. Those new features are available on HEAD though, so if you take a nightly build you'll get them. They'll all be in Swift (likely 4.0), which is due out later this year. See [Jeff Pott's blog](http://ecmarchitect.com/archives/2011/03/27/1308) for some more info on Swift.

The [Alfresco Team website](http://team.alfresco.com/) has a lot of info on Team on it, which should help you decide if it's a good fit for you, or if you need the full Community/Enterprise version.